# Aesthetics aside, is there a medical reason that acne should be treated?

Tags: dermatology

There are obvious costmetic reasons to treat Acne.

However, are there ***medical*** reasons for acne to be treated?

Possible ***disadvantages*** of treatment include harshness of chemicals, side effects of antibiotic use, side effects of Retin A, etc - depending on treatment regimen.

What would be medical ***advantages***?  Such as avoiding risk for infections, or other?

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE, bengy! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. Personalised medical advice is off-topic here. You may improve your question to comply with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [ask]. Thanks!

Comment: I provided an example of edit that more closely meets site guidelines.  You are welcome to reverse it if you disagree.

Comment: Risks/benefits should always be discussed with a doctor for individualized advice before beginning treatment, as no 2 people are the same.

Comment: @DoctorWhom Nice save.

Answer (score 4):

> What would be medical advantages?

There are several problems with what you're asking. It has to do with how you're framing the issue. But rather than get into a more convoluted point, I'll just answer your question:

1. Reduced psychosocial well-being
2. Longer term scarring

Maybe that matters to you, maybe it doesn't. For some people it can impact their life in a significant way, leading to depression, etc. Then again, the retinoid treatments for acne can also lead to depression or worse.

"Remaining a virgin at age 40" may not have an ICD-10 code, but it doesn't mean it's not a risk factor of acne worthy of attenuating.

> Such as avoiding risk for infections, or other?

No, quite the opposite is possible:

> https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamadermatology/fullarticle/398804
>
> **Antibiotic Treatment of Acne May Be Associated With Upper Respiratory
>   Tract Infections**
>
> **Objective**  To determine if the long-term use of antibiotics for the treatment of acne results in an increase in either of 2 common
>   infectious illnesses: upper respiratory tract infections (URTIs) or
>   urinary tract infections.
>
> **Design**  Retrospective cohort study.
>
> **Setting**  General Practice Research Database of the United Kingdom, London, England, from 1987 to 2002.
>
> **Patients**  Patients with a diagnosis of acne.
>
> **Main Outcome Measure**  The onset of either a URTI or a urinary tract infection.
>
> **Results**  Of 118 496 individuals with acne (age range, 15-35 years) who were identified in the General Practice Research Database, 84 977
>   (71.7%) received a topical or oral antibiotic (tetracyclines,
>   erythromycin, or clindamycin) for treatment of their acne and 33 519
>   (28.3%) did not. Within the first year of observation, 18 281 (15.4%)
>   of the patients with acne had at least 1 URTI, and within that year,
>   the odds of a URTI developing among those receiving antibiotic
>   treatment were 2.15 (95% confidence interval, 2.05-2.23; P<.001) times
>   greater than among those who were not receiving antibiotic treatment.
>   Multiple additional analyses, which were conducted to show that this
>   effect was not an artifact of increased health care–seeking behavior
>   among our cohorts, included comparing the cohorts of patients with
>   acne with a cohort of patients with hypertension and the likelihood of
>   developing a urinary tract infection.
>
> **Conclusions**  Patients with acne who were receiving antibiotic treatment for acne were more likely to develop a URTI than those with
>   acne who were not receiving such treatment. The true clinical
>   importance of our findings will require further investigation.

Comment: Do you mean oral antibiotics only?  Or are you talking even about  gels like duac and stuff like that?